# Get the followers list and wether the current user follows them or not

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to achieve the following with the cheapest cost and best performance:
(please think of millions of documents):

I have this collection : Followhip

```
{
“followee”: 12345,
“follower”:     54321,
“start”:        ISODate(“2013-08-21T12:34:00”),
“last”:     ISODate(“2013-08-23T06:00:00”),
“end”:      ISODate(“2013-08-23T07:50:23”)
```

}

last is the last scan date when `follower` was following `followee` 
now on a profile page, I get all the followers (limited to 10) , but also I want to check if the current user follows the followers.
the naive solution was to query foreach follower , with the criteria : 'follower' = current user and 'followee' = follower , if the result is empty , return false, else true.

My question is : is there better solution for this ? like MAP REDUCE or something , I'm a newbie in Mongodb , so maybe someone can help me here 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$in` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in) so you don't have to make ten queries, but only one, e.g.

```
// currentProfile.displayedFollowerIds = [ 32434, 54354, 656536, ... ]
db.followers.find( { followee : currentUser.Id, 
                     follower: {$in : currentProfile.displayedFollowerIds } });
```

Map/Reduce in MongoDB is not made for ad-hoc queries; a Map/Reduce operation has quite a bit of overhead in MongoDB and shouldn't be used like queries.

If you have complex queries, you might want to look at the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).